# How Android ListView add item don't use notifyDataSetChanged?

Tags: android, listview, notifydatasetchanged

I have a `ListView`, at bottom have a load more button.
When click load more button, add data from remote to add list adapter dataset.
Every list item have a big photo use ImageLoader to load.
When use adapter `notifyDataSetChanged`, all item will getView and all item will redraw, big photo will redraw, feel UI refresh.
Have a method notify new added item changed and only reload new item?

My adapter like this:

```
public class PhotoSquareAdapter extends BaseAdapter 
{
private List<PhotoRecom> data;
public PhotoSquareAdapter(List<PhotoRecom> data)
{
    this.data = data;
}
public void addList(List<PhotoRecom> d) {
    for (PhotoRecom n : d) {
        data.add(n);
        //addView(data.size() - 1);
    }
    super.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}
@Override
public PhotoRecom getItem(int position) {
    if (position >= getCount())
        return data.get(getCount() - 1);
    return data.get(position);
}
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final PhotoRecom item = getItem(position);
    final ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = li.inflate(R.layout.photo_square_list_item, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.iv_photo_square_listitem_head_thumbnail = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_photo_square_listitem_head_thumbnail);
        holder.iv_photo_square_city = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_photo_square_city);
        holder.tv_photo_square_nick = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_photo_square_nick);
        holder.tv_photo_square_title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_photo_square_title);
        holder.tv_photo_square_like = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_photo_square_like);
        holder.iv_photo_square_photo = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_photo_square_photo);
        holder.tv_photo_square_saw = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_photo_square_saw);
        holder.tv_photo_square_chat = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_photo_square_chat);
        holder.pb_loading_img = (ProgressBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.pb_loading_img);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    imageLoader.displayImage((url + item.getPhoto()), holder.iv_photo_square_photo, options);
    //...
    return convertView;
}
private class ViewHolder {
    ImageView iv_photo_square_listitem_head_thumbnail;
    ImageView iv_photo_square_city;
    TextView tv_photo_square_nick;
    ProgressBar pb_loading_img;
    TextView tv_photo_square_title;
    TextView tv_photo_square_like;
    ImageView iv_photo_square_photo;
    TextView tv_photo_square_saw;
    TextView tv_photo_square_chat;
}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't avoid calling `notifyDatasetChanged`. This will cause getView to be called at least for the rows that are on screen. You should be using some kind of cache for your images so that you don't have to always load them from nothing. There are plenty of libraries for this, or you can use [`LruCache`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/util/LruCache.html) from the support library.

Comment: The point to nail home in this is that you definitely shouldn't need to call an image load every time a list item view loads. That is really tedious work for a device. There are a number of ways to cache the data temporarily